# Deleting div animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, html

I want to delete a `div` and have all other `div`'s (after) within the wrapper reflow and animate (slide) nicely into their new places.  At the moment it flicks around, things don't always go in the right place, and general failure on my part.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CUzNx/30/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="item1" class="item">Test1</div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">Test2</div>
    <div id="item3" class="item">Test3</div>
    <div id="item4" class="item">Test4</div>
    <div id="item5" class="item">Test5</div>
    <div id="item6" class="item">Test6</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i ++)
{
    items[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle('hide');
    }
};
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
}
.item {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    min-height: 187px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 1% 1em 0;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.hide {
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `border: 0;` to `.hide`.

Comment: @KittMedia - It's certainly closer, but it still doesn't look right.  I want each item to slide into place (or animate somehow). See - http://jsfiddle.net/CUzNx/44/

Comment: Have you considered http://masonry.desandro.com/ ? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @3rror404 - Any tips on where to start with that?  Seems like a good library, but I just need this one function, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Vijay The problem is that a float cannot be animated by CSS only.

Comment: @KittMedia - Any tips on where to start?

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#remove - exactly what you're trying to achieve i think

Comment: @3rror404 - You are spot on.  If there is a pure JS way, I'd rather do it like that.  But put your answer down, at the very least it's worth an upvote :)

Comment: masonry is pure javascipt, if by that you mean it doesn't require JQuery. You can use it with or without JQuery. Also, I don't really consider linking to a library to be an answer so I wont add it as one.

Comment: I mean pure JS, as in, a simpler way than including a whole library.  I might dig into the code though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some joy using

```
display:inline-block;
```

Then in the JavaScript adding a timeout for the end of the animation, followed by a

```
this.style.display = none
```

### Link here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8BSkY/

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i ++)
{
    items[i].onclick = function() {
        var box = this
        this.classList.toggle('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
            box.style.display = 'none';
        },500);
    }
};
```

Then:

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    min-height: 187px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:1%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kryvp/)

I hope it will fullfill your requirement.

```
 $(".item").click(function(){

        $(this).animate({
            width: '0px',
            height:'100%',
            opacity:'0',
            margin:'0',
            padding:'0',
            left: '0px'

        });
    });
```

CSS

```
.item {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    min-height: 187px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 1% 1em 0;
    position: relative;
    background: white;


    transition:all 3s;
    transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition:all 3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Hi Majoj.  I can get that item to animate.  The problem is sliding all divs after the one being deleted into place.  If you look at your demo, after the initial animation, the rest just appear in place.

Comment: You cannot achieve this only via css or jquery, you must use some plugin like [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should hide the entire div for it to be completely unrendered. Add an event listener to the css animation and change it's style (or set another classname if you want)

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i ++)
{
    items[i].onclick = function(){
        this.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function( event ) { 
            this.style.display = 'none';
        }, false );
        this.classList.toggle('hide');
    }
};
```

P.S. That's webkit browsers only though.

- Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) use webkitTransitionEnd
- Firefox uses transitionend
- IE9+ uses msTransitionEnd
- Opera uses oTransitionEnd

Comment: Hey.  That seems to work exactly the same as the others.  Things flick into place.

Comment: What browser are you using?